# Parse HTML Table - PHP

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I have an HTML table that I would like to parse in PHP to store into a MySQL Database. The HTML looks like this:

> `<tr><td>DATE</td><td>LOCATION</td><td><a href="URL">NAME</a></td></tr>`

I would like to create a PHP function that returns in an array, the fields in capital letters. Does anyone know any php libraries that can do this, or should I be using a different language, as this may be complex. I don't know exactly how to do this with many tables on the page, but I am trying to parse the VEX events on [RobotEvents](http://www.robotevents.com/robot-competitions/vex-robotics-competition?limit=all). The table that I want to parse starts at line 465.

Comment: I am downloading the HTML file.

Comment: Have you looked at this, it might be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816194/how-to-parse-html-table-using-php

Comment: @Smith: See my updated answer for finding a specific table.

Comment: @Smith. Noticed you switched the accepted answer from mine to another. Is there a reason why? Did you find a problem with the library I suggested. Just curious to know what went wrong in case I have to recommend it to somebody else in future.

Comment: Your code didn't work as well as the other libraries suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're prepared to look beyond PHP, [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) (Ruby) and [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (Python) are well-established libraries that parse HTML very well.

That doesn't imply that there are no suitable PHP libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [PHP HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library.

To use, you can do something similar to this (not my example):

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = array();

$html = file_get_html('http://flow935.com/playlist/flowhis.HTM');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
    $time = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $artist = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;
    $title = $row->find('td',2)->plaintext;

    $table[$artist][$title] = true;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($table);
echo '</pre>';
```

There's some tutorials, SO questions and interesting reads about the library. It seems to be pretty popular.

- http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/
- [Looping through a table with Simple HTML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445371/looping-through-a-table-with-simple-html-dom)
- [how to print cells of a table with simple html dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277687/how-to-print-cells-of-a-table-with-simple-html-dom)

**UPDATE FOR FINDING SPECIFIC TABLE IN HTML USING ABOVE LIBRARY**

To find a particular table amongst many:

**1. By class:**

On line 465 of your scraped HTML, the table starts with a class `catalog-listing`, so:

```
foreach ($html->find('table[@class="catalog-listing"]')->find('tr') as $row) {
   // extract TD data
}
```

**2. By instance** (find 2nd table in HTML)

```
foreach ($html->find('table', 2)->find('tr') as $row) {
   // extract TD data
}
```